# Most efficient way to get a subset of tagged objects from acts_as_taggable find_tagged_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have a named scope `sfw_only` in my Image model that returns images with nsfw == false.

I'm also using `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` - and I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to do something like the following.

```
if !params[:tag].nil?
  if nsfw_mode
    @images = Image.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @images = Image.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
    ... remove images with nsfw == true
  end 
else
  if nsfw_mode
    @images = Image.all
  else
    @images = Image.sfw_only
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the acts_as_taggable_on_steroids. But the documentation leads me to believe it's compatible with named scopes.

So you should just be able to do

```
if !params[:tag].nil?
  if nsfw_mode
    @images = Image.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @images = Image.find_tagged_with(params[:tag]).sfw_only
    ... remove images with nsfw == true
  end 
else
  if nsfw_mode
    @images = Image.all
  else
    @images = Image.sfw_only
end
```

In the case that it doesn't you could make you're own named_scope that emulates finds_tagged_with and chain it with your sfw_only scope. [This post](http://codeintensity.blogspot.com/2008/11/speed-up-and-namedscope.html) describes how to do it, if it hasn't already been merged into the source.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize named scopes and finds were chainable.